# О слове "обширный"

Tags: семантика

Можно ли слово "обширный" применять в значении "большой по размеру"? Обширная корка арбуза, обширная виноградина, обширная лампа (стояла на столе).

Допустимы ли сочетания "обширнее ознакомиться", "обширнее изложить"?

Answer (score 1):

В значении просто "больший по размеру" - нельзя. Это прилагательное применяется для характеристики **пространств**, напр. географических территорий или - в переносном смысле - *областей* (напр. знания).

"Изложить обширнее" *можно* (рассказ, изложение может быть пространным или обширным по содержанию; в таком выражении свойства *содержания* переносятся на действие изложения), "ознакомиться" - едва ли: здесь на глагол не переносятся свойства "обширности" материала, правильнее "*ознакомиться подробнее* (или *познакомиться глубже*)".

Comment: Думаю, что "обширнее изложить" допустимо. В словаре есть значение синонима "подробный".

Comment: Конечно  - как синоним слова "подробнее" (пространнее). Я упустил последние два вопроса (если они были изначально).

Comment: "*Ознакомиться подробнее*" вряд ли удачно. Ознакомляются с материалом поверхностно. А *подробнее/обширнее* - это уже изучение. Да и сравнительная степень подразумевает, что ознакомление уже было ранее. А повторно ознакомляться не получится.

Comment: В сочетании "Ознакомиться обширнее" ознакомление может принимать свойство обширности "материала" для ознакомления. Например, речь идёт о культурных традициях русского народа. Содержание этой темы может обладать свойством обширности (так как обширность приложима к абстрактным понятиям). Почему же ознакомление не может отражать это свойство?

Comment: @oleedd В сравнительном варианте (по сравнению с тем же "поверхностным") - какие проблемы?

Comment: Во фразе нет, но в контексте те проблемы могут появится. Фраза ощущается как "*тебе следует ознакомится подробнее*". Но "подробнее" ещё ладно, а "обширнее" - это уже точно к изучению.

Answer (score 0):

***Обширнее изложить?***

**ИЗЛОЖИТЬ,** св. что. Сообщить, передать что-л. в связной форме, устно или письменно. И. просьбу. И. факты, взгляды, план, какой-л. вопрос, чьё-л. мнение. И. теорию, философию. И. студентам, слушателям, присутствующим. И. в книге, статье, в письме, в беседе, на бумаге. И. в ходе дискуссии. И. своими словами. И. устно, письменно.

Какова сочетаемость глагола? Изложить можно много чего, а как можно изложить? Кратко, подробно, по существу. Что там еще? Да вроде бы всё. **Мы не излагаем что-либо широко, обширно, шире и обширнее.**  Не согласны? Приведите примеры из авторитетных источников.

***Обширнее ознакомиться?***

**ОЗНАКОМИТЬСЯ**, св. с чем. Получить сведения, приобрести знания о чём-л. О. с резолюцией. Подробно ознакомился с обстановкой где-л. О. с чьей-л. характеристикой. О. с правилами и обязанностями граждан.

Проверим сочетаемость глагола. Ознакомиться можно кратко, подробно, ближе, лично, **но только не широко и не обширно, не шире и не обширнее.** Опять же при несогласии требуются авторитетные примеры из классики.

Примечание

**Возможная ошибка** при определении правильности выражения состоит в том, что **мы не можем самостоятельно "конструировать" словосочетания**, а должны проверять их по словарям или по факту употребления в письменной речи (только не по слуху, здесь вполне можно ошибиться).

Даже сходные по значению слова **не всегда являются взаимозаменяемыми** и могут использоваться в различных словосочетаниях.

Поэтому придумывать новые сочетания — это почти всё равно что **придумывать новые слова,** желательно помнить об этом. А лучше ничего не придумывать, а  контролировать наличие словосочетания в специальных словарях или в текстах, которым можно доверять. Также неплохо определить частотность их употребления.

Comment: Такой пример: *Нужно обширно изложить данную тему, чтобы все поняли суть.*

Comment: Ну да, скажите это где-нибудь, например: Вы так обширно изложили тему, я восхищен.  А потом наблюдайте за реакцией окружающих. Если они не расслышали, скажите громче или повторите несколько раз. Варианты такие: 1) Они приняли вас за иностранца, если вы на него похожи; 2)  Они приняли вас за провинциала с неправильной речью при соответствующем сходстве; 3) Они поняли это как иронию с неясным подтекстом и косо посмотрели на вас (в остальных случаях).

Comment: Чем мне не нравится это сочетание? Допустим, появилась у вас какая-то идея, с вашей точки зрения совершенно новая, и вы хотите ее "изложить на бумагу". Идейка так себе, небольшая,  можно это сделать в трех предложениях, а можно обширно изложить на 10 листах.

Comment: Другими словами, обширное изложение не воспринимается как достоинство, но может показаться растягиванием материала, неоправданным многословием автора. В сочетаниях учитывается прямое значение глагола: есть какой-то исходный объем чего-либо, который излагается (выкладывается) или полностью, или кратко, но только не обширно.  Поэтому  представить что-либо  обширно - это хорошо, а излагать обширно - комплимент весьма сомнительный.

Comment: Вполне себе достоинство: *Изложил обширно, аж на 10 листов. Молодец!* Да не вижу разницы между листами и темой. Но на листах уместнее звучит. Другое дело, что часто использоваться такое не будет. В словаре Кузнецова есть значение как синоним "подробный" и в наречии все значения остаются.

Comment: Так ничего и не поняли? Смотрим значения слов, подбираем похожие и составляем словосочетание? А про сочетаемость что-нибудь слышали? Вот у меня книжечка есть, называется "Словарь грамматической сочетаемости слов русского языка". Почитайте что-нибудь по теме.

Comment: Согласен, что не сильно сочетается. Но приемлемо. Alex_ander со мной согласен.

Comment: Насколько приемлемо, я вам уже объяснила, но вы юмора не понимаете.

Comment: Нет, не будет такой реакции. Смысл такой фразы довольно понятный. Да и при несочетаемости можно употребить кавычки, и будет "обширная" виноградина и "обширная" лампа.

Comment: Вот и ставьте везде кавычки,  только  их значение не все поймут однозначно. Будете "довольно грамотным" пользователем русского языка.

Comment: Но это при полной несочетаемости значений. Виноградина не может быть просторной или подробной. Но изложение - вполне. Оно не идеально сочетается. Но не настолько, чтоб ставить кавычки.

Comment: Вам задание. Наберите в Нацкорпусе слово "обширно", посмотрите, в каких словосочетаниях оно встречается. Там есть сочетание "излагать обширно"?  Какова семантика глаголов, которые сочетаются с этим наречием? Дайте характеристику этим глаголам.  Кратко  (не обширно) сформулируйте вывод из своих наблюдений. Пожалуй, всё.